# Change input background-image onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have one page (resto presentation), and one blue img (like icon).

When I click like_icon, if the user never vote for this resto, I want:
- to increase the vote (saving into mysql database as integer);
- show the new value in the page (without refresh page);
- change the like icon (red icon, always clickable);

If the user already voted, on click icon:
- descrease the vote (update the resto table);
- show the new value in the page (without refresh page);
- change the like icon to blue img (always clickable).

This is what I have tried, but not works properly. What is wrong? And how can I do this?

Thank you.

HTML:

```
...
...
 <?php include 'test.php'; ?>

<div id="idlike"><?php echo $idlike[0]; ?></div>

<label for="like">
    <img id="likeimg" src="/img/like.png" style="cursor: pointer;" />
<script>
 var x = document.getElementById("idlike").value;

 if (x > 0) {
  $("#likeimg").attr('src', '/img/dislike.png');
  //document.getElementById("likeimg").innerHTML = <img scr="/img/dislike.png">;
 }
 else {
  $("#likeimg").attr('src', '/img/like.png');
  //document.getElementById("likeimg").innerHTML = <img scr="/img/like.png">;
 }
</script>
</label>

<div id="likeimg"></div>

<form method="POST" action="resto-test.php?id=1">
    <input type="submit" id="vote" name="vote" value="" style="display: none;" />
</form>

<script>
$("#likeimg").click(function(){
    $("#vote").click();
});
</script>
...
...
```

test.php:

```
<?php
 //date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Bucharest");
 require('login/dbconfig.php');
 session_start();

 $login_session = $_SESSION['login_user'];
 $idresto = 1;

 $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$login_session'";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);
 $iduser = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 //$query = "SELECT id FROM likes WHERE id_user = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$login_session')";
 $query = "SELECT id FROM likes WHERE id_user = $iduser[0]";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);
 $idlike = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 //echo "<div id='idlike'>";
 //if ($idlike[0]) {
  //echo $idlike[0];
 //}
 //else {
  //echo "0";
 //}
 //echo "</div>";

 $query = "SELECT COUNT(id_resto) FROM likes WHERE id_resto = $idresto";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);
 $nrl = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
   if (!$idlike[0]) {
     //echo "<div id='likes'><img id='likeimg' src='/img/like.png'>";
     //echo "<div id='likes'><img id='likeimg' src='/img/like.png'>";

     $query = "INSERT INTO likes (id, id_user, id_resto, id_fel, id_gr) VALUES (default, $iduser[0], $idresto, 0, 0)";
     $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);

     $query = "UPDATE restos SET likes = ($nrl[0]+1) WHERE id = $idresto";
     $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);

     //echo "<span id='likenr'>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($nrl[0] + 1). "</span></div>";
     echo "<span id='likenr'>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($nrl[0] + 1). "</span>";
     $img = '/img/like.png';
   }

   else {
     //echo "<div id='likes'><img id='likeimg' src='/img/dislike.png'>";

     $query = "DELETE FROM likes WHERE id = $idlike[0]";
     $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);

     $query = "UPDATE restos SET likes = ($nrl[0]-1) WHERE id = $idresto";
     $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $query);

     //echo "<span id='likenr'>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($nrl[0] - 1). "</span></div>";
     echo "<span id='likenr'>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($nrl[0] - 1). "</span>";
     $img = '/img/dislike.png';
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You can do this using ajax. Internet is full of manuals, read one and try.

Comment: Use icons as `background-image` for clickable element.Then you will be able to switch them by CSS.

Comment: Ok, but, if the user has already voted, and visits the resto page again, I want it to remember the Like icon: show the red Like icon and not blue Like icon (I'm afraid that the switch between background-img is valid only when the user is on the page)